# Eclipse IDE: How to automatically arrive at the end of the current line after typing into a green box?

Tags: eclipse

For example while writing a method with 3 arguments, pressing tab automatically shifts to each argument spaces, but how to jump to the end of the current line without having to press END key?

Is it possible to use tab to move to the far end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press 'Enter', that exits the 'linked mode' (or as you call the green boxes)

Comment: how do you re enter the linked mode after you accidently get out of it by pressing Enter? great answer.

Comment: You need to perform an action that creates the linked mode again. You cannot undo and re-enter linked mode.

Answer (score 0):

Press INTRO...

The answer is to short... well, I tell you, when you press INTRO inside the green box, you reach to the end of the line :) .